# combine queries into one select statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

T1:
[image]

T2:
[image]

Expected result
[image]

Query 1:
select name,
sum(qty) as total,
count(distinct ids) as head
from t1
group by 1

Query 2:
select
count(distinct ids) as staff
from t2
join t1
on t1.id = t2.id
and files>0
where
t2.type='Mutual'

Query 1 gives name,total,head,files

Query 2 gives staff

But how to combine both into a single query? Redshift doesnt seem to support "staff=(select......)" in select statement.

Example: that doesn't work
select name,
sum(qty) as total,
count(distinct ids) as head,
staff = (select
count(distinct ids)
from t2
join t1
on t1.id = t2.id
and files>0
where
t2.type='Mutual')
from t1
group by 1

Comment: Why is `head=2` in expected result? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: head = count(distinct id) from table 1. John, Abe. Hence, 2